# How can we change ModelForm instance before sending it to template as response?

Tags: python, django

I wonder if we can change the field values of instance of a ModelForm in Django view. For example, I have this:

models.py

```
class hotel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel', verbose_name="Hotel Image")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    country = models.ForeignKey('country', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    state = models.ForeignKey('state', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    city = models.ForeignKey('city', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "hotels"


class Hotel(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = hotel
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
form = Hotel()
```

Is it possible to modify the city, state and country fields of this form before I pass it to the Django template:

```
        return render(request, 'web/hotels.html', {'form':form})
```

I am trying to send empty values for state and country fields to the Django template.

Comment: What do you mean "send empty values for state and country fields"? If you initialise the form with `form = Hotel()` then the initial values are already empty. In the template you should see a `select` widget (pull down menu) with all states and countries, but initially nothing is selected (empty value).

Comment: State, city, country are foreignkey fields. So, when I pass the form instance from view and access it in template like : form.as_p, it populates all the state and country values from the table into its corresponding dropdowns.

Comment: I understood what you understood I meant by empty is different. I mean, I dont want any values in the dropdowns of state and city at all

Comment: Yes, that's what should happen. But what do you want? Why are you showing the fields at all if you don't want to show anything? An empty dropdown doesn't really make sense.

Comment: You are right in a way. However, I am trying to show empty city and state initially, and when user selects a country, it loads states of that specific country only (otherwise, it slows down loading while populating all countires, states and cities in the world, which doesnt make sense at all). I could manually make drop downs, I know, but instead I am trying to load those fields but as empty, to save from doing manual work

Comment: Ah, then you should override your `city` and `state` fields in your form and change them to `ModelChoiceField` with empty queryset. But to then load the correct states belonging to a country, you will need to write an API to fetch the states based on the country and call it in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I had another post where a user shared this: 

def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
  super().__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)
  if not data:
   self.fields['state'].queryset = state.objects.none()
   self.fields['city'].queryset = state.objects.none()

and it works fine but when I proceed to save form, it gives error "__init__() got multiple values for argument 'data' ". I have already written working javascript and API, but can you help me how to override city and state fields in form? I am still learning Django.

Comment: The user also shared this:

    state = forms.ModelChoiceField(state.objects.all())
    state.choices = []
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(city.objects.all())
    city.choices = []

but it gives error

Comment: Your first method (in the `__init__` method) is the correct way to go. Maybe post a new question showing what you do and specifically how you instantiate the form with the error trace.

Comment: Hi. I solved it with code in my previous comment ( state = forms.ModelChoiceField(state.objects.all()) state.choices = [] city = forms.ModelChoiceField(city.objects.all()) city.choices = []). I kept initial value of country to blank, so now it loads only countries with first entry as blank. And when a user selects a country, it loads its states and then city from states using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
state = forms.ModelChoiceField(state.objects.all()) 
state.choices = [] 
city = forms.ModelChoiceField(city.objects.all()) 
city.choices = []
```

Then, I wrote jQuery code that listens to change in value of dropdown of country or state, and loads its corresponding state and country respectively. I kept initial value of country to blank, so now it loads only countries with first entry as blank. And when a user selects a country, it loads its states and then city from states using jQuery.

In short:
Load empty values in state and city -> write Ajax jQuery for change events of country and state (which will populate state on country change, and will populate city on state change).

PS - jQuery's .done() didnt work for me when trying to load cities "after" states were loaded. So, I passed a parameter 'flag' to my Ajax function and kept its value to 1 when country is changed and 2 when state is changed. And in success attribute of Ajax, if flag is 1 (i.e. state is changed), I called the Ajax function again to load cities (with flag 2).